# Manipulating CSV file with a non standardized content

Tags: java, csv

I have a CSV file with a non standardized content, it goes something like this:

```
John, 001
01/01/2015, hamburger
02/01/2015, pizza
03/01/2015, ice cream
Mary, 002
01/01/2015, hamburger
02/01/2015, pizza
John, 003
04/01/2015, chocolate
```

Now, what I'm trying to do is to write a logic in java to separate them.I would like "John, 001" as the header and to put all the rows under John, before Mary to be John's.

Will this be possible? Or should I just do it manually?

**Edit:** 
For the input, even though it is not standardized, a noticeable pattern is that the row that do not have names will always starts with a date.
My output goal would be a java object, where I can store it in the database eventually in the format below.

```
Name, hamburger, pizza, ice cream, chocolate
John, 01/01/2015, 02/01/2015, 03/01/2015, NA
Mary, 01/01/2015, 02/01/2015, NA, NA
John, NA, NA, NA, 04/01/2015
```

Comment: So every line that starts with a name marks the beginning of a new CSV "file"?

Comment: It is indeed possible, but it would be easier if you said what are the actual specs for the input file instead of letting us guess. An example is useful but it is not a full spec.

Comment: @Tichodroma yes, you are right.

Comment: In addition to showing us the pattern for input, you need to define what success looks like in terms of the output. Are you trying to build new output files? or java objects? Why is the data this unstructured in the first place?

Comment: @SergeBallesta Actually that is what the file looks like, oh and I forgot to mention that the line without names will start with a date. I'll edit my question.

Comment: @user486174 Please leave the markup of the CSV as it is: indented with four spaces. Backticks are for markup inside a normal text line.

Comment: @AshleyFrieze Thanks, I will edit the question further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just read the file into a list

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(path), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Afterwards iterate over the list and split them for wanted delimiters `(",")`.

Now you could just use if-else or switch blocks to check for specific entries.

```
List<DataObject> objects = new ArrayList<>();
DataObject dataObject = null;
for(String s : lines) {
    String [] splitLine = s.split(",");
    if(splitLine[0].matches("(\d{2}\/){2}\d{4}")) {
        // We found a data
        if(dataObject != null && splitLine.length == 2) {
            String date = splitLine[0];
            String dish = splitLine[1];
            dataObject.add(date, dish);
        } else {
            // Handle error
        }
    } else if(splitLine.length == 2) {
        // We can create a new data object
        if(dataObject != null) {
            objects.add(dataObject);
        }
        String name = splitLine[0];
        String id = splitLine[1];
        dataObject = new DataObject(name, id);
    } else {
        // Handle error
    }
}
```

Now you can sort them into your specific categories.

**Edit:** Changed the loop and added a regex (which may not be optimal) for matching the date strings and using them to decide whether to add them to the last data object.

The DataObject class can contain data structures holding the dates/dishes. When the CSV is parsed you can iterate over the objects List and do whatever you want. I hope this answer helps :)

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP question - you'd have to modify it to look at splitLine[0] and detect if it looks like a date. If it's a date, then it adds to the previous item's data, otherwise it's the start of a new item.

Comment: Hm, I thought that would be implicated with my answer, therefor the do stuff comments, here he could check if it's a date and then add it to the previous item's data.

Comment: You have some hard coding for data items within the code. "John" for example. I think that's not what is needed.

Comment: It now should be more generic :)

Comment: @TimoH Thanks! Just some question though, what does the line 
}else if (splitLine.length == 2){  used for? Also, I try to run the code with additional entries in the csv but somehow if there are 3 names, only 2 names will be put in the object. Seems like the last dataObject will not be added to the objects List.

Comment: Oh I managed to make sure all the names are inside the objects by shifting the objects.add(dataObject); to the end of the else if statement.

Answer (score 2):

If I have correctly understood, the specs are :

- input is text, one record per line (fields are comma delimited)
- 2 kinds of records :

  - *headers* consisting of a name and a number (number is ignored)
  - actual records consisting of a date and a meal
- output should contain :

  - one header containing the constant *Name*, and the meals in order of occurence
  - on record per name consisting with the name and the dates corresponding to the meals - an absent field will have *NA* constant string
- we assume that we will never get for a name the same date for different input records.

The algorithm is in pseudo code :

```
Data structures :
 one list of struct< string name, hash< int meal index, date> > for the names : base
 one list of strings for the meals : meals

Code :

name = null
iname = -1
Loop per input lines {
  if first field is date {
    if name == null {
      throw Exception("incorrect structure");
    }
    meal = second field
    look for index of meal in meals
    if not found {
      index = len(meals);
      add meal at end of list meals
    }
    base[iname].hash[index] = date
  }
  else {
    name = first field
    iname += 1
    add a new struc { name, empty hash } at end of list base
  }
}
close input file
open output file
// headers
print "names"
for meal in meals {
  print ",", meal
}
print newline
for (i=0; i<=iname; i++) {
  print base[i].name
  for meal in meals {
    look for meal in base[i].hash.keys
    if found {
      print ",", base[i].hash[meal]
    }
    else {
      print ",NA"
    }
  }
  print newline
}
close output file
```

Just code it in correct Java and come back here if you have any problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use [uniVocity-parsers](https://github.com/uniVocity/univocity-parsers#reading-master-detail-style-files) to handle this for you. It comes with a master-detail row processor.

```
// 1st, Create a RowProcessor to process all "detail" elements (dates/ingredients)
ObjectRowListProcessor detailProcessor = new ObjectRowListProcessor();

// 2nd, Create MasterDetailProcessor to identify whether or not a row is the master row (first value of the row is a name, second is an integer).
MasterDetailListProcessor masterRowProcessor = new MasterDetailListProcessor(RowPlacement.TOP, detailProcessor) {
    @Override
    protected boolean isMasterRecord(String[] row, ParsingContext context) {
         try{
             //tries to convert the second value of the row to an Integer.
             Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(row[1]));
             return true;
         } catch(NumberFormatException ex){
             return false;
         }
    }
};

CsvParserSettings parserSettings = new CsvParserSettings();

// Set the RowProcessor to the masterRowProcessor.
parserSettings.setRowProcessor(masterRowProcessor);

CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(parserSettings);
parser.parse(new FileReader(yourFile));

// Here we get the MasterDetailRecord elements.
List<MasterDetailRecord> rows = masterRowProcessor.getRecords();

// Each master record has one master row and multiple detail rows.
MasterDetailRecord masterRecord = rows.get(0);
Object[] masterRow = masterRecord.getMasterRow();
List<Object[]> detailRows = masterRecord.getDetailRows();
```

Disclosure: I am the author of this library. It's open-source and free (Apache V2.0 license).